# Is bitly supported for Native Script?

Tags: nativescript

Where can i find the documentation of integrating **bitly** in **Native script** application

I did not find any documentation for bitly with cross platform(Native script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may access / integrate any native (Objective C / Java) api / libraries within {N}. There is no plugin available for bitly as of now. So you will have to write one or at least directly access their APIs within your project.

Go through the [iOS](https://dev.bitly.com/sdk_ios.html) / Android integration guide on bitly then marshall the [Objective C](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/Marshalling-Overview) / [Java](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js) into JS / TS. Optionally you may wrap it as a [plugin](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugin-reference).